# PHP automated email script

Tags: php, email, automation

Id like to generate an automatic email at certain times of the week or daily from my website to certain users. i.e at 12am, or 5pm .I'd like an email reminder sent to user example@example.com. Can anyone point me in the right direction. I have read about cronjob but didn't got much information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking in the right direction... A cronjob would suffice.
This would allow you to run a php script on a schedule

Start by looking [here](http://docs.phplist.com/SetupCronJob)

Comment: :Is there any other way than cronjob?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have shell access to your host? Or does the host have CPanel installed?

If you have shell access, you can run the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

Then insert a new line like this:

```
* 0,17 * * * /path/to/php/executable /path/to/script/which/sends/emails.php
```

This will call your PHP script every day at hours 0 and 17 (12AM and 5 PM). The email sending should be done in `/path/to/script/which/sends/emails.php`

Comment: :Is there any other way than cronjob?

Comment: On linux not that I am aware of... everybody uses them. On windows yes, there are Tasks which are basically the same thing as cron jobs only much easier to set up and it offers much more configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create php script which will do all work (get data to send, get emails list, send data). After that You need to assign this script to schedule in crontab

Comment: Is there any other way than cronjob?